# PyMongo sending "authenticate" for every query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, python-rq

I am getting an authentication to MongoDb for every query I run using PyMongo MongoClient. This seems expensive / unnecessary:

```
2015-02-13T09:38:08.091-0800 [conn375243]  authenticate db: { authenticate: 1, user: "", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-02-13T09:38:08.876-0800 [conn375243] end connection xxx (15 connections now open)
2015-02-13T09:38:08.962-0800 [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx:42554 #375244 (16 connections now open)
2015-02-13T09:38:08.966-0800 [conn375244]  authenticate db: { authenticate: 1, user: "", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using the same MongoClient (although it's hidden behind MongoEngine) and not intentionally disconnecting it at any point:

```
19:20:45 {'default': MongoClient('xxx-a0.mongolab.com', 39931)}
19:20:45 [139726027002480]
19:28:35 {'default': MongoClient('xxx-a0.mongolab.com', 39931)} # print mongo_client_instance
19:28:35 [139726027002480] # print id(mongo_Client_instance)
```

When I set a pdb breakpoint in the authenticate function, this is the stacktrace. I cannot figure out why asking the cursor to refresh requires a fresh authentication. Am I misunderstanding, and that is part of the MongoDb protocol? My goal is to have as few "authenticate" commands sent as possible, since right now they're 50% of my logged commands on the server.

```
 /home/ubuntu/workspace//metadata/jobs.py(24)get()
-> b = Item.objects.get_or_create(id=i['id'])[0]
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py(241)get_or_create()
-> doc = self.get(*q_objs, **query)
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py(182)get()
-> result = queryset.next()
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py(1137)next()
-> raw_doc = self._cursor.next()
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py(1058)next()
-> if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py(1002)_refresh()
-> self.__uuid_subtype))
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py(915)__send_message()
-> res = client._send_message_with_response(message, **kwargs)
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py(1194)_send_message_with_response()
-> sock_info = self.__socket(member)
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py(922)__socket()
-> self.__check_auth(sock_info)
  /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py(503)__check_auth()
-> sock_info, self.__simple_command)
> /home/ubuntu/workspace//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py(239)authenticate()
-> mechanism = credentials[0]
```

Additional information that might be useful is that these calls are from a Python RQ worker. I am trying to set up the connection before the fork step, but it's possible something is happening there to cause this.

```
(Pdb) os.getpid()
10507
... next query...
(Pdb) os.getpid()
10510
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

The default Python-RQ worker uses the fork model, and the forking blocked PyMongo from sharing connection sockets.

I switched to the [GeventWorker](https://github.com/zhangliyong/rq-gevent-worker) and now the sockets are shared by default.